# AutoMocking classes with non-interface dependencies... Does a framework support this?

Tags: mocking, tdd, moq, automocking

I am trying to mock a class that has a dependency on a concrete class, just like:

[AutoMockContainer with support for automocking classes with non-interface dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462340/automockcontainer-with-support-for-automocking-classes-with-non-interface-depend)

I tried 3 different AutoMocking Frameworks (UnityAutoMoq, AutoMoq and AutoMockContainer contained in Moq.Contrib).  None of these frameworks support creating mocks for concrete dependencies.  I understand Mark Seeman has given an example on how to do this with autofac, but I don't understand why it's not supported out of the box from these frameworks.  Is there a framework that supports this that I didn't try ?  If not, can someone help me to do this with Unity ?

Me and a colleague have banged our heads against this all day long without finding an answer, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inherently this is not supported. At least non of the frameworks you mentioned above. Auto Mocking builder strategy the code goes as below

```
if (type.IsInterface || type.IsAbstract)
{
    context.Existing = GetOrCreateMock(type);
    context.BuildComplete = true;
}
```

The Moq.Mock uses Castle Dynamic proxies and it is not capable of generating dynamic proxies on non-virtual types.

On a separate note:
I personally believe this is for a good reason as not letting creating proxies on non-virtual types allow developers use virtual types often i.e abstract/interfaces. This also means interface based programming and helps for testability and maintainability which promotes better design.

If you really want these capablities the next step would be looking at non-proxy based mock object frameworks such as TypeMock, which are not free.

Comment: 'Interface-based programming' shouldn't require a literal C#/Java interface construct. A virtual method is still a vtable lookup, and a class' public members are an interface in the software design sense even if the class doesn't implement an interface in the C#/Java sense. Many languages don't have a construct similar to the C#/Java interface, yet nearly all languages offer the ability to have an interface in the sense of software design.